# How to display answers in separate rows in a HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have this query below:

```
SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, q.QuestionMarks
FROM Session s
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
WHERE s.SessionName =  "GHWSW1" AND q.QuestionId = 1
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
```

The query above outputs this result below:

```
SessionId   SessionName QuestionId  QuestionContent         Answer  QuestionMarks
1           GHWSW1       1          Here are 2 answers      BD      5
```

So I included the query in the code below and set up a html table:

```
$assessment = "GHWSW1";
$number = 1;

$query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
   FROM Session s 
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
   WHERE s.SessionName = ? AND q.QuestionId = ?
   GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
   ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
   ";

   // prepare query
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   // You only need to call bind_param once
   $stmt->bind_param("si", $assessment, $number);
   // execute query
   $stmt->execute(); 


       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
   $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      } 

?>      

</head>

<body>



<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<?php 

echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
      </tr>\n";

          foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>' ;
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

        ?>
```

So the HTML table displays it like this:

```
QuestionId  QuestionContent         Answer  QuestionMarks
1           Here are 2 answers      BD      5
```

But I want it like this in the html table:

```
QuestionId  QuestionContent         Answer  QuestionMarks
1           Here are 2 answers      B       5
                                    D
```

The second Answer `D` should be in a seperate row and the other rows should have a rowspan. But how can this be achieved?

Session Table:

```
SessionId (auto)  SessionName
1                 AAA
```

Question Table:

```
SessionId  QuestionId (auto)  QuestionContent
1          1                  What is 2+2?
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId (auto) SessionId  QuestionId   Answer
1               1          1           B   
2               1          1           D
```

Comment: You can't, since you're doing a group_concat in the query, you're destroying the very information you need to signal that a new row is called for. you COULD use a `<br>` as the separator. that'd give you multiple lines, but still just a single cell, saving you having to calculate rowspans.

Comment: That's what I call: a good formating! And also, your MySQL query is awesome! (Sorry, I only have a small knowledge in MySQL)

Comment: @MarcB It is ok, I figured it out. needed to get rid of the GROUP CLAUSE as well and then include some code in the foreach loop so that it will display blank information in rows which needs to be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

    echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>' ;
    echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

you forget to close the tr tag

Comment: I actually figured it just out. I had to get rid of a group by clause and add a somethings in a foreach loop. I will answer the question to show. But I will give you best answer if you can tell me how to span rows if they are empty. I will provide my answer so you can see the code. Here is a link to show what the table looks like [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/individualmarks.php)

Comment: I posted my answer, have a look at the answer and the link I provided in the comments

Comment: ur link is broken , you mean , you want show a row even if its empty?

Comment: Sorry here is the link [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/individualmarks.php). What I mean is that when you see the table, the empty rows under the "QuestionNo", "Question", "Marks Per Answer" and "Total Marks" columns, I then to span so that it looks like one cell and not separate cells, does that make sense?

Comment: sorry your link ask for login. have you the try login names and password ? if i see this table i think maybe i understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the GROUP BY clause and add make the foreach loop look like this:

```
echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
      </tr>\n";
                $previous_question_id = null;
          foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
            if ($previous_question_id == $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
          $searchQuestionId[$key] = '';
          $question = '';
          $searchMarks[$key] = '';
      }else{
          $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
      }
        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="answertd">';
        echo $searchAnswer[$key];
        echo '</td>' ;
        echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" "/></td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}      
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
```